# SSH with two factor authentication

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I am trying to use two factor authentication on my server so that when I ssh from my **mac terminal** it will ask a username and password as well as performing two factor authentication.

I checked and found lots of results about this, But somehow I am not able to install it from terminal, I also tried to use **google authentication** too. I am not sure whether it requires me to install something in order to use two factor authentication.

I checked links like
[bruienne](http://enterprisemac.bruienne.com/2015/01/07/enable-google-two-factor-authentication-for-ssh-connections-on-os-x/)
[digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-two-factor-authentication)

I also try to follow steps as in this link
[howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/),

But when I run this command on terminal

```
    sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator
```

I am getting sudo: apt-get: command not found, Not sure what I can do here?

Can any one please guide me here or provide a link that can guide me?

Comment: apt-get is a Linux command, no such thing for OSX. You should search for a guide that installs two-factor authentication on a MacOSX

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - I am almost positive he is asking about how to enable this functionality on his Linux VPS.

Comment: @Ramhound If so, my bad!!! Then it means he is on a CentOS VPS (most likely), in which case he cannot find apt-get because this is a Debian-distro package manager. **If** the same guide can be used *verbatim* for CentOS, then yum should be used in its stead.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - I extrapolated the Linux (VPS) server because of his links.  He also indicated that he is connecting to something from the mac terminal.  But honestly its not all that clear I admit.

Comment: sorry for bad explanation. I am on osx, and trying to add two factor authentication while ssh from my mac terminal. I just got success with this link (steps for osx). http://enterprisemac.bruienne.com/2015/01/07/enable-google-two-factor-authentication-for-ssh-connections-on-os-x/
Thanks  MariusMatutiae,  Ramhound to guide and reply.